# Export high quality image with M2DOC

Tags: m2doc

How can I change my code M2DOC code for export a image/diagram in high quality?

This is the code that I would like to improve:

```
{m:rep.asImage().setHeight(600)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [fit()](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_imageservices.html#orgobeonetworkm2docelementmimagefitinteger-integer--orgobeonetworkm2docelementmimage) service:

```
{m:rep.asImage().fit(400, 400)}
```

Also you can parameter the quality of images exported by Sirius in the preference menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this setting solve my problem!